# Как скрыть AppBarLayout и Fragment при прокрутке вниз и показывать при прокрутке вверх в андроиде?

Tags: android

Разметка xml такова.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout android:id="@+id/main_content"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.shop.a1.collapsing.activities.MainPageActivity"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:id="@+id/app_bar"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:layout_behavior="com.shop.a1.collapsing.data.ScrollAwareAppBarBehavior">

            <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlwaysCollapsed">

                <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="pin">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|snap"
                        android:weightSum="5"
                        android:paddingRight="8dp">

                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:src="@mipmap/glass"
                            android:scaleX="0.8"
                            android:scaleY="0.8"
                            android:id="@+id/glass"
                            android:layout_weight="1"/>

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:text="Shop"
                            android:textColor="#AAAAAA"
                            android:id="@+id/app_name"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:textSize="18sp"
                            android:layout_weight="3"/>

                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:src="@mipmap/bag"
                            android:scaleX="0.8"
                            android:scaleY="0.8"
                            android:id="@+id/bag"
                            android:layout_weight="1"/>

                    </LinearLayout>

                </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

            </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:background="#ffffff"
                android:weightSum="4"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

                <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                    android:id="@+id/tabs"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"

                    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                    android:background="#ffffff"
                    android:layout_weight="3"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:background="#f94536"
                    android:paddingLeft="12dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:id="@+id/catalog">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Каталог"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:paddingRight="4dp"
                        android:textColor="#ffffff"/>

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:src="@mipmap/fourtht"
                        android:paddingLeft="4dp"/>

                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
            android:layout_below="@+id/app_bar"
            android:layout_above="@+id/bottom_nav_view"/>

        <fragment
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/bottom_nav_view"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:name="com.mobishop.a1.collapsing.BottomNavigationViewFragment"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```